# Android java .contains() int in object list

Tags: java, android, list, integer, contains

I connect to an url and read the entire page into a string and then split the string on comma's and store everything in a list with the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

bodyHtml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
items = Arrays.asList(bodyHtml.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

I need to check if certain integers exist with `.contains()` in this list but the list itself is `java.lang.object`

How can I make the list an integer list and not an object list or how can I check for existing integers within the object list?

Comment: what is `items` ? can you show the response you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `bodyHtml.split("\\s*,\\s*")` will return a `String` array. Subsequently, the statement `Arrays.asList(bodyHtml.split("\\s*,\\s*"));` will return a `List<String>`. You should therefore be able to assign the result to a `List<String>` :

`List<String> items = Arrays.asList(bodyHtml.split("\\s*,\\s*"));`.

You now have two options to search the list :

1. If your `searchKey` does not necessarily have to be an `Integer`, you can search the `List` by passing a `String` to the `contains` method
2. If your `searchKey` has to be an `Integer`, you can convert the search key to an `String` by using `searchKey.toString()` and pass it the to `contains` method.

That being said, this approach will only work when there is an exact match. If you want a partial match, `List.contains` is not the way to go. The quickest solution would be to iterate through the `List<String>` and call `String.contains(searchKey)` on each element in the list.

Comment: SearchKey being a string wont be a problem but how do i turn an object to string? This is what i'm checking for, where do i put `.toString()`? `allItems_filtering.results(i).data_id`

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg I am not sure what `allItems_filtering.results(i).data_id` really does but yes, you can use `toString()` to convert an `Integer` to a `String`.

Comment: I didn't need the data_id to be an int so I changed it to a stringand now it's working with my old code, thanks anyway